# Save the last table id column value in the foreign key table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net

```
Create table employeedetails
EmployeeId int primary key identity,
Employeename varchar(50)

Create table applyleaves
EmployeeId int, 
Constraint fk_key foreign key (Employeeid) 
References employeedetails(EmployeeId)
```

Now lets assume employee id= 101 and name =xxxx

```
Create procedure insertion(forapplyleaves) 
@EmployeeId
AS
BEGIN
    insert into applyleaves values (@EmployeeId) 
END
```

Now I want the `employeeid` of first should be same and automatically set into second table `employeeid` column

I have two tables employee details and apply leave.

How can I set `applyleave.employeeid` same as `employeedetails.employeeid` using a stored procedure?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Sql server @jarlh

Comment: @jarlh from next time i will thanks alot for suggestion.... Now should i post new question or you can tell

Comment: Edit the question add sample table data and expected result (formatted text, no images), also show us your current code attempt.

Comment: @jarlh edited you can check it out

Comment: Sample data is where you provide a couple of rows of data - not just the table definition. And then you show the expected result i.e. the rows of data afterwards.

Comment: If by "did it" you mean you managed to solve your problem, then add an answer yourself so that anyone else coming across this question can see how to solve it.

Comment: @DaleK sorry for this i have not solved till yet

Comment: Then add some sample data and expected results and someone will help you.

Comment: Here is the [last question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61584744/select-top-rows-until-value-in-specific-column-has-appeared-twice), see how it provides sample data, my attempt, my results and my expected results. When you ask a question with that level of detail you will normally get an answer very fast.