# Select top rows until value in specific column has appeared twice

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I have the following query where I am trying to select all records, ordered by date, until the second time `EmailApproved = 1` is found. The second record where `EmailApproved = 1` should not be selected.

```
declare @Test table (Id int, EmailApproved bit, Created datetime);

insert into @Test (Id, EmailApproved, Created)
values
  (1,0,'2011-03-07 03:58:58.423')
  , (2,0,'2011-02-21 04:55:52.103')
  , (3,0,'2011-01-29 13:24:02.103')
  , (4,1,'2010-10-12 14:41:54.217')
  , (5,0,'2010-10-12 14:34:15.903')
  , (6,0,'2010-10-12 10:10:19.123')
  , (7,1,'2010-08-27 12:07:16.073')
  , (8,1,'2010-08-25 12:15:49.413')
  , (9,0,'2010-08-25 12:14:51.970')
  , (10,1,'2010-04-12 16:43:44.777');

select *
  , case when Row1 = Row2 then 1 else 0 end Row1EqualRow2
from (
  select Id, EmailApproved, Created
    , row_number() over (partition by EmailApproved order by Created desc) Row1
    , row_number() over (order by Created desc) Row2
  from @Test
) X
--where Row1 = Row2
order by Created desc;
```

Which produces the following results:

| Id | EmailApproved | Created | Row1 | Row2 | Row1EqualsRow2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2011-03-07 03:58:58.423 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 2011-02-21 04:55:52.103 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 2011-01-29 13:24:02.103 | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 2010-10-12 14:41:54.217 | 1 | 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 2010-10-12 14:34:15.903 | 4 | 5 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 | 2010-10-12 10:10:19.123 | 5 | 6 | 0 |
| 7 | 1 | 2010-08-27 12:07:16.073 | 2 | 7 | 0 |
| 8 | 1 | 2010-08-25 12:15:49.413 | 3 | 8 | 0 |
| 9 | 0 | 2010-08-25 12:14:51.970 | 6 | 9 | 0 |
| 10 | 1 | 2010-04-12 16:43:44.777 | 4 | 10 | 0 |

What I actually want is:

| Id | EmailApproved | Created | Row1 | Row2 | Row1EqualsRow2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2011-03-07 03:58:58.423 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 2011-02-21 04:55:52.103 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 2011-01-29 13:24:02.103 | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 2010-10-12 14:41:54.217 | 1 | 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 2010-10-12 14:34:15.903 | 4 | 5 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 | 2010-10-12 10:10:19.123 | 5 | 6 | 0 |

Note: `Row`, `Row2` & `Row1EqualsRow2` are just working columns to show my calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps:

1. Create a row number, `rn`, over all rows in case `id` is not in sequence.
2. Create a row number, `approv_rn`, partitioned by `EmailApproved` so we know when `EmailApproved = 1` for the second time
3. Use a `outer apply` to find the row number of the `second` instance of `EmailApproved = 1`
4. In the `where` clause filter out all rows where the row number is `>=` the value found in step 3.
5. If there is 1 or 0 `EmailApproved` records available then the `outer apply` will return null, in which case return all available rows.

```
with test as
(
    select  *, 
            rn         = row_number() over (order by Created desc),
            approv_rn  = row_number() over (partition by EmailApproved 
                                                order by Created desc)
    from    @Test
)
select  *
from    test t
        outer apply
        (
            select  x.rn
            from    test x
            where   x.EmailApproved = 1
            and     x.approv_rn     = 2
        ) x
where   t.rn    < x.rn or x.rn is null
order by t.Created desc;
```