# Select union distinct records from two tables on the basis of common column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, union

I want to union Table1 and Table2 and select distinct records. If the Transaction_id is same in both the tables, I want the record from Table1 (not from Table2 at all). Could someone please write a SQL Server query for me?
I am trying below query for this but I am getting duplicate records.

```
Select * from Table1
union
Select * from Table2
```

**Table1**

```
Transaction_id  Product Quantity    Return
     1           Pen       2       No DATA
     2           pencil    4       No DATA
     3           sharpner  6       No DATA
     4           eraser    10      No DATA
```

**Table2**

```
Transaction_id  Product Quantity    Return
     3           sharpner   6       Yes
     5           Book       9       Yes
```

**Union Table**

```
Transaction_id  Product Quantity    Return
     1           Pen       2       No DATA
     2           pencil    4       No DATA
     3           sharpner  6       No DATA
     4           eraser    10      No DATA
     5           Book      9       Yes
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am using table1 unions table2 and not getting correct output. Could you please help me?

Comment: Show us your query as it stands...

Comment: I just updated the question with my query.

Comment: If you make it easy for me, by adding the DDL/DML statements I'll take a look. [Example of creating DDL/DML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61584744/select-top-rows-until-value-in-specific-column-has-appeared-twice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following and here is the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/addd2/20).

```
select
  transaction_id,
  product,
  quantity,
  retur
from table1

union all

select
  transaction_id,
  product,
  quantity,
  retur
from table2 t2
where not exists (
  select
    transaction_id
  from table1 t1
  where t2.transaction_id = t1.transaction_id
)
```

Output:

```
*------------------------------------------*
|transaction_id  product quantity   retur  |
*------------------------------------------*
|  1               Pen        2     No DATA|
|  2               pencil     4     No DATA|
|  3               sharpner   6     No DATA|
|  4               eraser     10    No DATA|
|  5               book       9      yes   |
*------------------------------------------*
```

Comment: Thanks for saving my day! The actual table has 15M records and around 60 columns with such conditions. Your query perfectly worked for me. Spot on! Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `full join` and conditional logic here:

```
select
    coalesce(t1.transaction_id, t2.transaction_id)transaction_id,
    case when t1.transaction_id is not null then t1.product else t2.product end product,
    case when t1.transaction_id is not null then t1.quantity else t2.quantity end quantity,
    case when t1.transaction_id is not null then t1.return else t2.return end return
from table1 t1
full join table2 t2 on t1.transaction_id = t2.transaction_id
```

Note that `return` is a language keyword, hence not a good choice for a column name.

Comment: @JohnBristiw: let me pinpoint that this should be more efficient that the `union`/`not exists` solution, because it does not involve multiple table scans.

Comment: you are absolutely right, this method is faster because it does not involve multiple table scans. Thanks