# Create a query that displays the employees with no sale in the last 3 days from a date to customers who are from "USA". northwind database

Tags: sql, sql-server, northwind

I want to get the employees with no sale in the last 3 days before 1997-01-25 to customers who are from "USA".

**Orders table**

```
OrderID CustomerName    EmployeeId  Orderdate
10248   C1               1             1997-01-25 00:00:00:000
10249   C2               3             1997-0-24 00:00:00:000
10250   C3               2             1997-01-23 00:00:00:000
10251   c4               5             1997-01-22 00:00:00:000
10251   c5               4             1997-01-23 00:00:00:000
```

Employees

```
EmployeeID  Emp_name
1            E1
2            E2  and so on till e5
```

Customers

```
CustomerID   Country
C1            USA
C2            UK
C3            Brazil
C4            UK 
C5            USA
```

**Desired result**

```
EmployeeID
2
3
5
```

**Query tried**

```
select EmployeeID
from Employees e1
where employeeid not in
(
    select o.EmployeeID
    from orders o
    full join customers c on o.CustomerID=c.CustomerID
    where c.Country = 'USA' 
    and o.RequiredDate >= dateadd(day,-3, '1997-01-25')
)
```

- There were total e1 to e5 employees.
- e1 served customer c1 on 25th Jan 1997 . c1 is from usa
- e4 served customer c4 on 23 jan 1997 (within 3 days before 25th jan, 1997) and c4 is from usa.
- So get a list of employees not in e1 and e4 from total list of employees.

However I am getting blank result, as in no rows. can anyone pls help. (this is just a specimen): data from northwind database. I have just created sample data in case someone does not have northwind database

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could start providing the DDL/DML statements to create the sample data in your questions. Makes it much easier of people to answer them.

Comment: I have to ask, you are asking a large number of questions, many of them very similar, are you learning from the experience? I would have thought by now that you would be able to write some of these queries by yourself. I think I saw you mention that they are interview questions - if you don't actually understand how to do it yourself its not going to help you in a job?

Comment: `full join` will return all Employees whatever `on` conditions

Comment: Your syntax if wrong at a basic level e.g.  `select EmployeeID, from` is already broken, its got an extra comma which won't compile. If thats what you really tried, then it never even worked?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61584744/select-top-rows-until-value-in-specific-column-has-appeared-twice) is an example of how to setup the DDL/DML statements for us. Its makes your question so much easier to answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but no one is being forced to solve a problem. SO is a platform where ppl solve each other's problems. Let us avoid personal and unprofessional remarks pls. If you feel a particular question is not useful, kindly do not answer it or ignore it...I have taken your suggestion for DDL though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based entirely on the table data you "provided", the problem is that you are looking for an Employee id of integer and your sub-query is returning a list of employee names.  So if you modify it as such you will get the correct answer:

```
CREATE TABLE #Orders (OrderID int, CustomerName varchar(20), EmployeeName varchar(20), Orderdate datetime)
INSERT INTO #Orders VALUES
(10248, 'C1', 'E1', '1997-01-25 00:00:00:000'),
(10249, 'C2', 'E3', '1997-01-24 00:00:00:000'),
(10250, 'C3', 'E2', '1997-01-23 00:00:00:000'),
(10251, 'c4', 'e5', '1997-01-22 00:00:00:000'),
(10251, 'c5', 'e4', '1997-01-23 00:00:00:000')

CREATE TABLE #Employees (EmployeeID int, Emp_name varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #Employees VALUES
(1, 'E1'),
(2, 'E2'),
(3, 'E3'),
(4, 'E4'),
(5, 'E5')

CREATE TABLE #Customers (CustomerID varchar(10), Country varchar(20))
INSERT INTO #Customers VALUES
('C1', 'USA'),
('C2', 'UK'),
('C3', 'Brazil'),
('C4', 'UK' ),
('C5', 'USA')

select Emp_name
from #Employees e1
where Emp_name not in
(
    select o.EmployeeName
    from #orders o
    inner join #customers c on o.CustomerName = c.CustomerID
    where c.Country = 'USA' 
    and o.Orderdate >= dateadd(day,-3, '1997-01-25')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Employees.Emp_name
FROM Employees
LEFT JOIN Orders ON Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID AND Orders.Orderdata BETWEEN '1997-01-23' AND '1997-01-25'
LEFT JOIN Customers ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID AND Customers.Country = 'USA'
AND Customers.CustomerID IS NULL
```