# Transform line-by-line values from another table to a string and insert it into NOT IN clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, notin

I am trying to exclude a series of test users from 'test_user' table by using `NOT IN`.

[image: test_user table]

I got another 'member' table with userID and other information

[image: member table]

Originally, the tester user table is not too long, so people use `NOT IN` clause to exclude test users by listing their ID, but as the test users increase day by day, I am wondering if there is any way to keep this `NOT IN ()` up-to-date and easy to maintain.

I am not sure if there is any solution like:

```
@declare test_user varchar(23) = select ID from test_user

SELECT * FROM member WHERE ID NOT IN (@test_user)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please don't use images for data, instead use DDL+DML statements for sample starting data, and formatted text for expected results.

Comment: Don’t over think it. Unless the performance degrades excessively, do nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. When you mention "DDL+DML" statement, do you mean CREATE TABLE table_name (....)? for the expected results, could you kindly share an example? Thanks again!

Comment: Create a temp table, and insert sample data - that way people can copy and paste for testing. Expected results can be just formatted text. You should be doing that yourself as part of creating a [mre] - and its not uncommon to solve your own problem while building the MRE. Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61584744/select-top-rows-until-value-in-specific-column-has-appeared-twice)

Comment: @DaleK thanks! I will follow this example in the future. Also, your solution works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the variable... just insert your query directly as the `not in` list.

```
SELECT *
FROM member
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM test_user);
```

Note: It makes life easier to use a consistent casing and layout for your queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM MEMBER M
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM TESTUSER T 
    WHERE T.ID = M.ID)
```

OR You can use the `LEFT JOIN` as follows:

```
SELECT M.* 
  FROM MEMBER M LEFT JOIN TESTUSER T ON T.ID = M.ID
 WHERE T.ID IS NULL;
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN WHERE NULL` is nearly always less performant than a straight anti-join (your first option)

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to modify the `member` table?  If so, you can add a new column `is_test_user`.  Then you can query using

```sql
SELECT *
FROM member
WHERE is_test_user = 0
```

<s>If you do this, I recommend adding an index on `is_test_user` as well.</s>

Edit: Since the question had been updated, my answer no longer fits.

Edit 2: Removed the index recommendation per Bohemian's suggestion.

Comment: Adding an index on a boolean column will have no effect due to lack of sufficient cardinality. However, there may be a small performance increase if there is a covering index on both id and is_test_user.

Comment: hi Karn, unfortunately, I cannot modify the member table. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @Bohemian thanks for the suggestion.  I assumed that the number of test users would be a small percentage, where the index could be useful.  Which might or might not be correct.  In any case, OP cannot modify the member table.

Comment: You'd still need a way of keeping the table updated, commonly triggers, which could easily overcomplicate the situation.