# How do I pull in duplicate charges based upon certain criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find duplicate orders within the dataset that I can search from.

Table: Transaction_Data

Columns: Guest_ID, Order_ID, Name, Quote_Date, Arrival_Date, Sale_Location, Product_Code and Deposit_Amount

| Guest_ID | Order_ID | Name | Quote_Date | Arrival_Date | Sale_Location | Product_Code | Deposit_Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123455 | Guest1 | 12/1/2022 | 12/20/2022 | Location1 | Product1 | 100 |
| 1 | 123456 | Guest1 | 12/1/2022 | 12/20/2022 | Location1 | Product1 | 100 |
| 2 | 123457 | Guest2 | 12/2/2022 | 12/21/2022 | Location2 | Product2 | 105 |
| 3 | 123458 | Guest3 | 12/3/2022 | 12/22/2022 | Location3 | Product3 | 110 |
| 1 | 123459 | Guest1 | 12/1/2022 | 12/20/2022 | Location1 | Product1 | 100 |

I have tried the following but have not had good luck:

```
SELECT Guest_ID,Order_ID,COUNT(Order_ID) AS Quantity,Name,Quote_Date,Arrival_Date,Sale_Location,Product_Code,Deposit_Amount 
FROM Transaction_Data WHERE Quote_date >='2022-11-01' and Deposit_Amount NOT LIKE '-%'
GROUP BY Guest_ID,Order_ID,Name,Quote_Date,Arrival_Date,Sale_Location,Product_Code,Deposit_Amount
HAVING COUNT (Order_ID) >1
ORDER BY Order_ID,Guest_ID
```

```
SELECT Guest_ID,Order_ID,Name,Quote_Date,Arrival_Date,Sale_Location,Product_Code,Deposit_Amount 
INTO #TempOrder
FROM Transaction_Data WHERE Quote_Date >='2022-11-01' and Deposit_Amount NOT LIKE '-%'

SELECT Guest_ID,Order_ID,
(SELECT MAX (Order_ID)
FROM Transaction_Data TD
WHERE TD.Order_ID < TO.Order_ID
) AS Prev_Order,
(SELECT MIN(Order_ID)
FROM Transaction_Data TD
WHERE TD.Order_ID > TO.Order_ID
) As Nxt_Order, TO.Name,TO.Quote_Date,TO.Arrival_Date,TO.Sale_Location,TO.Product_Code,TO.Deposit_Amount
FROM #TempOrder
```

This is giving me the Order_ID that is before and after, but is not giving me duplicates based upon the Guest.

If you look at the above table I am attempting to pull in only the following records:

| Guest_ID | Order_ID | Name | Quote_Date | Arrival_Date | Sale_Location | Product_Code | Deposit_Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123455 | Guest1 | 12/1/2022 | 12/20/2022 | Location1 | Product1 | 100 |
| 1 | 123456 | Guest1 | 12/1/2022 | 12/20/2022 | Location1 | Product1 | 100 |
| 1 | 123459 | Guest1 | 12/1/2022 | 12/20/2022 | Location1 | Product1 | 100 |

EDIT: I will do better next time I have an answer, but this has been answered.

I ended up putting these into a temp table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempRes;

SELECT rth.ip_number,
       ror.reservation_id,
       COUNT(ror.reservation_id) OVER (PARTITION BY rth.ip_number,
                                                    ror.quote_date,
                                                    rdd.deposit_amount
                                       ORDER BY ror.reservation_id
                                      ) AS quantity,
       MIN(ror.reservation_id) OVER (PARTITION BY rth.ip_number, ror.quote_date, rdd.deposit_amount) AS min_order,
       ror.name,
       ror.quote_date,
       ror.arrival_date,
       rth.sale_location_code,
       rdd.deposit_amount
INTO #TempRes
FROM dbo.r_order_reservation ror
    JOIN dbo.r_transaction_header rth
        ON rth.reservation_id = ror.reservation_id
    JOIN dbo.r_transaction_detail rtd
        ON rtd.reservation_id = ror.reservation_id
           AND rtd.product_header_code != '7777777'
    JOIN dbo.r_deposit_detail rdd
        ON rdd.reservation_id = ror.reservation_id
WHERE ror.quote_date > '2022-12-01'
      AND ror.operator_id = 'freeride'
      AND rdd.deposit_amount NOT LIKE '-%';

SELECT *
FROM #TempRes tr
WHERE tr.quantity > 1
ORDER BY tr.reservation_id,
         tr.ip_number;

DROP TABLE #TempRes;
```

This gave me the quantity of each but also grouped them together correctly.
Thank you!

Comment: 1) Does your sample data show all the scenarios you want to test for? 2) Please show your desired results from the sample data as tabular data since words are just not as clear. 3) If you  want to make it easy for someone to assist, provide the sample data as DDL+DML so they can copy and paste it out and directly run it, rather than having to manually type it all in.

Comment: @DaleK I am attempting to pull together duplicated Order_ID when referencing the same Guest_ID, but to filter out all of the other Order_ID that are not duplicated.

The Guest_ID, Name, Quote_Date,Arrival_Date,Sale_Location, Product_Code and Deposit_Amount will be the same with different Order_IDs.

I am not trying to use the above Queries, just added what I tried. I am having a hard time figuring out how to pull in these duplicated records so I figured giving all the data of what I've tried and am trying to accomplish was best.

I will add another comment showing a table.

Comment: @DaleK Needed Output based upon the above table would be:

Guest Order     Name          QD                    AD                   SL                   PC   DA
1 123455 Guest1 12/1/2022 12/20/2022 Location1 Product1 100
1 123456 Guest1 12/1/2022 12/20/2022 Location1 Product1 100
1 123459 Guest1 12/1/2022 12/20/2022 Location1 Product1 100

I am trying to pull together these records based upon the same guest but to remove all other guests that do not have duplicated records. I am having issues because the Order_ID is different so grabbing dups seems to be more difficult than anticipated.

Comment: @DaleK Sorry if what I put is confusing, this is the first time I've asked a question here and have been googling stuff all day trying different things. To be honest, I don't know what type of query would need to be written to get the outcome I am looking for. Thanks in advance! SEND HALP!

Comment: @DaleK How would I provide the sample data as DDL+DML? I know that DDL references CREATE, ALTER,DROP,TRUNCATE etc and DML references SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE etc.

I'm not sure how I would provide that information as I don't know what needs to be done to get the data grouped together correctly. 

I'm trying to help you help me, just a tad confused. Thanks.

Comment: See how I've done it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61584744/select-top-rows-until-value-in-specific-column-has-appeared-twice) - note I am asking for sample data in this form, i.e. the raw (example) data that you want to process... I'm not asking for your desired results in this form.

Comment: You've just added your desired results - great. Note you can probably simplify your question a huge amount down to; I have this data, I want these results, this is the logic, and this is what I tried. The rest of the background history tends to add confusion just because there is so much text to read.

Comment: We generally advise against editing your own post to provide an answer. It can be useful to post your own answer if you also post along with it additional information or reasoning as to why the other answers were not adequate, however if you do post your own answer you should not accept it if other answers provided you the insights necessary to find your specific implementation.

Comment: It is also poor form to provide a code example in your answer that uses different tables/fields to those that were described in the original question. That makes this hard for other readers to follow, they might even think that you have used some special function or keywords to transpose the query. Remember your question and the answers it generates are more for the community than they are for you, which is a strange concept at first, but this question will remain long after you have moved on from it. It is up to us to leave it in a good state for those who will follow in our footsteps. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in your Grouping expression, you have included `Order_ID` but that is unique, so not duplicated. To find a duplicate you need to remove that field from the comparison.

[This response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61584932/1690217) highlights a standard solution to selecting *just the duplicated records* by using the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) window function that *partitions* by your grouping set, then we return only the records that were *not* the first record in the set, so only the duplicates, not the original.

- Window functions provide us a way to evaluate aggregate expressions across a dataset inline with the entire set, so without actually grouping the results.

There is a caveat, we need to use a CTE or subquery to calculate the Window Function if we want to filter or group on the results of the aggregation.

```
;WITH AggregatedData as
(
    SELECT Guest_ID,Order_ID
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( 
            PARTITION BY Guest_ID, Quote_Date, Product_Code,Deposit_Amount 
            ORDER BY Order_ID
        ) AS Order_Duplicate
        ,Name,Quote_Date,Arrival_Date
        ,Sale_Location,Product_Code,Deposit_Amount 
    FROM Transaction_Data WHERE Quote_date >='2022-11-01' and Deposit_Amount NOT LIKE '-%'
)
SELECT Guest_ID,Order_ID,Name,Quote_Date,Arrival_Date
    ,Sale_Location,Product_Code,Deposit_Amount 
FROM AggregatedData 
WHERE Order_Duplicate > 1
ORDER BY Order_ID,Guest_ID
```

This should return just the duplicated records, which is often more useful because these represent the transactions that most likely need to be reversed or refunded.

| Guest_ID | Order_ID | Name | Quote_Date | Arrival_Date | Sale_Location | Product_Code | Deposit_Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123456 | Guest1 | 12/1/2022 | 12/20/2022 | Location1 | Product1 | 100 |
| 1 | 123459 | Guest1 | 12/1/2022 | 12/20/2022 | Location1 | Product1 | 100 |

If you want to return *ALL* of the records where there is a duplicate, then we can use the window query version of `COUNT()` with the [`OVER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) clause which is very similar:

```
;WITH AggregatedData as
(
    SELECT Guest_ID,Order_ID
        ,COUNT() OVER( 
            PARTITION BY Guest_ID, Quote_Date, Product_Code, Deposit_Amount 
            ORDER BY Order_ID
        ) AS Quantity
        ,Name,Quote_Date,Arrival_Date
        ,Sale_Location,Product_Code,Deposit_Amount 
    FROM Transaction_Data WHERE Quote_date >='2022-11-01' and Deposit_Amount NOT LIKE '-%'
)
SELECT Guest_ID,Order_ID,Name,Quote_Date,Arrival_Date
    ,Sale_Location,Product_Code,Deposit_Amount 
FROM AggregatedData 
WHERE Quantity > 1
ORDER BY Order_ID, Guest_ID
```

| Guest_ID | Order_ID | Name | Quote_Date | Arrival_Date | Sale_Location | Product_Code | Deposit_Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123455 | Guest1 | 12/1/2022 | 12/20/2022 | Location1 | Product1 | 100 |
| 1 | 123456 | Guest1 | 12/1/2022 | 12/20/2022 | Location1 | Product1 | 100 |
| 1 | 123459 | Guest1 | 12/1/2022 | 12/20/2022 | Location1 | Product1 | 100 |

---

We can extend this further by including both of the `COUNT` and `ROW_NUMBER` results in the output or we can use other aggregates like `MIN`:

```
;WITH AggregatedData as
(
    SELECT Guest_ID,Order_ID
        ,COUNT() OVER( 
            PARTITION BY Guest_ID, Quote_Date, Product_Code, Deposit_Amount 
            ORDER BY Order_ID
        ) AS Quantity
        ,MIN(Order_ID) OVER( 
            PARTITION BY Guest_ID, Quote_Date, Product_Code, Deposit_Amount 
        ) AS Min_Order_ID
        ,Name,Quote_Date,Arrival_Date
        ,Sale_Location,Product_Code,Deposit_Amount 
    FROM Transaction_Data WHERE Quote_date >='2022-11-01' and Deposit_Amount NOT LIKE '-%'
)
SELECT Guest_ID,Order_ID,Quantity,Min_Order_ID,Name,Quote_Date
    ,Arrival_Date,Sale_Location,Product_Code,Deposit_Amount 
FROM AggregatedData 
WHERE Quantity > 1
ORDER BY Order_ID, Guest_ID
```

| Guest_ID | Order_ID | Quantity | Min_Order_ID | Name | Quote_Date | Arrival_Date | Sale_Location | Product_Code | Deposit_Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123455 | 3 | 123455 | Guest1 | 12/1/2022 | 12/20/2022 | Location1 | Product1 | 100 |
| 1 | 123456 | 3 | 123455 | Guest1 | 12/1/2022 | 12/20/2022 | Location1 | Product1 | 100 |
| 1 | 123459 | 3 | 123455 | Guest1 | 12/1/2022 | 12/20/2022 | Location1 | Product1 | 100 |

- Technically we could have used `MIN` as the first example, and filtered where the result of `MIN` did not equal the `Order_ID` but that syntax is harder to interpret if you are not familiar with these concepts.

---

### Update: Without CTE

Common Table Expressions (**CTE**/`WITH`) *and* the Window Query Functions (`OVER()`) were both introduced in SQL Server 2005. If your SSMS supports `OVER()` then it will also support `WITH`. A caveate to using `WITH` is that it must be the first stratement in an expression, the simple way around this is to  add a `;` prefix any time you use `;WITH`. I have updated this post to reflect this convention.

If you do not want to, or cannot use a CTE, then a simple nested query will do the same job:

```
SELECT Guest_ID,Order_ID,Quantity,Min_Order_ID,Name,Quote_Date
    ,Arrival_Date,Sale_Location,Product_Code,Deposit_Amount 
FROM (
    SELECT Guest_ID,Order_ID
        ,COUNT() OVER( 
            PARTITION BY Guest_ID, Quote_Date, Product_Code, Deposit_Amount 
            ORDER BY Order_ID
        ) AS Quantity
        ,MIN(Order_ID) OVER( 
            PARTITION BY Guest_ID, Quote_Date, Product_Code, Deposit_Amount 
        ) AS Min_Order_ID
        ,Name,Quote_Date,Arrival_Date
        ,Sale_Location,Product_Code,Deposit_Amount 
    FROM Transaction_Data 
    WHERE Quote_date >='2022-11-01' 
      and Deposit_Amount NOT LIKE '-%'
) AggregatedData 
WHERE Quantity > 1
ORDER BY Order_ID, Guest_ID
```

Comment: @DaleK I just accepted the answer and I will approach my question differently next time with the help and other post you've provided.

Comment: @SunBrnt I've updated the post with a non-CTE solution. It is a bit overkill to use temporary tables for a simple operation like this.